# Python: creating and changing list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to initialize a list, but then I have to change each cell in said list. I did:

```
matrix = [[[0] * len(t[0])] * len(t[0])]
```

But when trying to change one cell it changes the entire column of the matrix. Why is this?

Comment: len(t[0]) is variable, deppends on user. The only problem is on the list/matrix @DylanLawrence

Answer (score 1):

Yes the problem is that you are copying references and not creating new objects, to solve that you can do something like this:

```
matrix = [[0 for _ in xrange(len(t[0]))] for _ in range(len(t[0]))]
```